# How to read a string line by line in C++

Tags: c++

I have a string with an xml code in it. I want to read from it line by line so i can extract the strings betweens "title" tags.
I know how to extract the titles, but how do i traverse the string ?
Sounds easy but i have no idee right now.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why not simply use an XML parser?

Comment: i cand't, i need to parse myself the code :)

Comment: Parsing XML manually is a sketchy idea at best. You really should use a parser. Why can't you?

Comment: its an assigment, and my problem is that i dont know how to iterate a string so i can print all of the titles, not just the first one,like i am doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can give some more details about what extracting the strings between the "title" tags means?

If you already can extract the title tags, then that means you know their positions, so then extracting the string is just a matter of taking the substring between the opening and closing title tags right?

Are you looking for a XML parser? The opensource [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) works well, and has bindings for a variety of languages. There are other parsers, what parsers allow you to do is to take the XML string and create a tree data structure which gives you easy access to the elements of the XML.

EDIT: Originally the requirement about not using an xml parser didn't exist in the question. Here's a rough algorithm to create your own XML parser.

1) Create a tree data structure, and a recursive parse() function.
2) Search for a XML tag, anything with the pattern <...>. Add the "..." tag to one of the child nodes of the current node you are on, and call the recursive parse() function again.
3) If you find a XML tag that closes the orginal <...>, then you are done with parsing that block. Go back to step #2. If there are no other blocks then return from the parse function.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
// node: The current node in the tree
// current_position: the current position in the XML string that you are parsing
// string: the XML string that you are parsing.
parse(node, current_position, string):
    while current_position < len(string):
        current_position = find(string[current_position:len(string)], "<...>")
        if !found: return current_position // should be end of string if nothing is found.
        node.children[node.num_children] = new Node("<...>");
        current_position = parse(node.children[node.num_children],current_position+size_of_tag,string)
        current_position = find(string[current_position:len(string)], "</...>")
        node.num_children++
    return current_position
```

Comment: i dont need parser, ye i can extract the text between the titles, but only the first one from the string, not the rest, because i dont have an ideea how to iterate in the string line by line...

Comment: @vBx: to extract lines you can use boost::tokenize, or `string::find` and `substr`...

Comment: @Tony: the extraction part is done, but i am only extracting the first title, because i dont have a while() to iterate the string, thats its my problem, how do i iterate it ?:)

Comment: @vBx: the easiest way: `#include <sstream> std::istringstream iss(my_multiline_string); std::string line; while (getline(iss, my_multiline_string)) { /* do stuff with line here */ }`

Comment: @vBX: Not sure what you mean by you don't have "while". You can just use add a while loop to whatever tokenize function you have right?

Comment: @Tony: isnt line gonna be empty all the time how you wrote ? :-/

Comment: @DasBoot: with other words, what condition do i put in the while, so i can traverse all of my string lines ?

Comment: @Tony: i guess its while(iss, line) there

Comment: @vBx: sorry - just seen your queries - should have been `while (getline(iss, line)) ...`, but I guess you've found that yourself. Cheers.